# Jetty 7 Spring 3.0.5 integration

Tags: spring, jetty

I am new to Jetty and Spring technology. I trying actually ton integrate Spring 3.0.5 to Jetty 7 but i am having every a error message.

My configuration its Mac Os X Lion, Eclipse Indigo, Jetty 7, Spring 3.0.5.

Did someone use Eclipse with jetty embedded with spring framework ? I

```
     2011-10-24 21:47:28.060:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-7.5.2.v20111006
    2011-10-24 21:47:29.094:INFO:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:NO JSP Support for /, 
    did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
    2011-10-24 21:47:29.146:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:Failed startup of context  
    o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/,file:/Users/benjamin/Documents/workspace/jettyserver/WebContent/}
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

`jettyserver.java`

```
    public static void main(String[] args)   {

      Server server = new Server(8080);

      WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
      context.setResourceBase("../jettyserver/WebContent");
      context.setDescriptor("../jettyserver/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml");
      context.setContextPath("/");
      context.setParentLoaderPriority(true);

      HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
      handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[]{ context, new DefaultHandler()});

      server.setHandler(handlers);
      //server.setHandler(context);
      try {
           server.start();
           server.join();
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
 }
```

`web.xml`

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
      id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

   <display-name>Spring3MVC</display-name>

   <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
          org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

   </web-app>
```

`spring-servlet.xml`

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
         <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
          xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

     <context:annotation-config />
         <context:component-scan base-package="com.jetty.controller" />

         <bean id="viewResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
         <property name="viewClass"
           value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
         <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
         <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
         </bean>
```

---

OK finally i am able to run the jetty 7 but nothing happen when i tape 
in safari this url localhost:8080/hello. I added the @RequestMapping in the controller for /hello. Here my main

```
      Server server = new Server(8080);

      WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
      context.setResourceBase("../jettyserver/webapp");
      context.setContextPath("/");
      context.setParentLoaderPriority(true);

      HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
      handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[]{ context, new DefaultHandler()});

      server.setHandler(context);
```

Its like spring is not mapping my controller. Did i do something wrong ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you'd like to add additional information to your question, just edit your question (click the 'edit' link underneath your question). To comment on an answer you've received, use the comment facility under the answer. If you find the comment space insufficient, you should probably be making an edit. Answers should be just that, direct answers to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's several answers saying essentially the same thing:

- http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.ide.eclipse.jetty.user/324
- http://manolocarrasco.blogspot.com/2009/09/tip-enabling-jsp-support-in-jetty700.html
- http://old.nabble.com/NO-JSP-Support-for---our-application-,-did-not-find-org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet-td25473044.html

I *am* a little curious how you searched; all I did was search on "jetty" plus the "No JSP support" string.

Comment: Well i was searching jetty + spring or jetty spring inteation etc... i checked all but most of them was not working. ill check those link asap.

Comment: @benjamin1111 Always best to start by searching for the error message/exception text--sometimes it's useless, but it's generally a good place to being :)

Comment: i searched but found to solve. I think its because Jetty 7 its new  andvthe most information i found wasvfor Jetty 6 or spring 2.5.

Comment: @benjamin1111 The second link is for Jetty 7. In any case, it's still the same issue.

Comment: @benjamin1111 AFAICT adding the support libs is enough as per [this](http://www.benmccann.com/dev-blog/embedded-jetty/). In any case, all this info should be more than enough to get you going.

Comment: OK the first link help to compile and error message disappear. Actually, Jetty need commons-el and tomcat jasper lib to compile the jsp part. But now, i am getting a new error message : 

2011-10-25 18:04:54.612:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-7.5.2.v20111006
2011-10-25 18:04:55.723:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/,file:/Users/benjamin/Documents/workspace/jettyserver/WebContent/}
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: Turn logging up to DEBUG level and see what's in the logs. That should come as a new question, though. Also, check out the SO FAQ and the info about [voting/accepting answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Glad you got it a bit more working :)

Comment: BTW here solution for my problem. I created a folder named wepapps in WEB-INF and set the resource base to wepapps.
Server server = new Server(8080);

      WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
      context.setResourceBase("../jettyserver/webapp");
      context.setContextPath("/");
      context.setParentLoaderPriority(true);

      HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
      handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[]{ context, new DefaultHandler()});

      server.setHandler(context);